# Delete first of two headers - Python

Tags: python, header, multi-index

i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
SP_removed

    Date    Removed
    Date    Ticker  Security
0   January 7, 2021     TIF     Tiffany & Co.
1   December 21, 2020   AIV     Apartment Investment & Management
2   October 12, 2020    NBL     Noble Energy
3   October 9, 2020     NaN     NaN
4   October 7, 2020     ETFC    E*TRADE Financial
...     ...     ...     ...
258     December 5, 2000    OI  Owens-Illinois
259     December 5, 2000    GRA     W.R. Grace
260     December 5, 2000    CCK     Crown Holdings
261     July 27, 2000   RAD     RiteAid
262     December 7, 1999    LDW     Laidlaw

263 rows × 3 columns
```

I want to delete the first header (Date and Removed), but everything i've tried so far didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `droplevel()` to get rid of the first row column names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['location1','location2'],
                                     ['S1','S2','S3']],
                                    names=['loc','S'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), 
                  index=['a','b','c','d','e'], 
                  columns=header)

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df
```

Comment: Happy to help - Next time would be great to come with [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Thanks